# Webstorm 8.0 live view not working

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am trying to use the live edit of webstorm while developing an angular js app, but it seems to disconnect from the server and I have to every time refresh the page in order for the changes to reflect onto it . I tried checking if the appropriate plugins are installed, yes they are. Tried reinstalling things, but am still stuck on it .Anybody please help me out .

Comment: what WebStorm version do you work with? Please check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/101809103-JavaScript-Debugging-Live-Edit-Chrome-extension-disconnects-in-a-few-seconds?page=1#post_26790026 - can it be an issue? See also http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Live+Edit for some hints on using Live Edit

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you have both activated LiveEdit in webstorm and installed advised chrome plugin.

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html

Live edit is provided by debug session. You need to know that session (and also live edit) will stop working when you open devtools or close status line which is in the top 
"Jetbrains Ide plugin" is debugging this tab"

If you let this note be, it should work.